# How to download apps on 4gb storage so I can move it to the SD card?

Tags: insufficient-memory, storage

I have a HTC Wildfire S, and it's only got 4GB storage. I have a 16GB mirco SD card, but I can't download things because I'm out of the 4GB space (I don't know how ... ), so I can't get them installed so I can then move them to the SD card. I'm not great with technology, so I may be missing something, but this is just really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Overflow!

To answer your question, you will need to move apps to your SD card off of system storage after their downloaded.  You can't download directly to the SD card, unfortunately.

Once an app is downloaded, open up Application Management in Settings and click the check box next to the apps you want to move to SD.  This should free up some space.  Be advised, however, that not all apps can run from the SD card.

It's in your best interest to clean up as much as you can, rather than trying to stuff apps on your SD card.  In the Data section of Settings, you can see what items are taking up the most space.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move apps from the internal storage into the SD card. Go to `settings app -> apps -> (select large apps)`. Next, you'll need to move the apps you've installed on that list. System apps are not allowed to be moved. In the app settings under storage, there is usually a move to SD card option, although not all apps support it. Look for ones you can move. You can move some apps to get your 4gb storage clear without uninstalling any application

I've added some photos of where you'll find this setting.
[image]